# Where are there guidelines for when&where to use each of the action bar icons?

Tags: android, icons, android-actionbar, android-icons

### background

the action bar is now widely used, but other than the [android assets studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_example&theme=light&color=33b5e5,60) website, there is no where to find native icons, and even on the website, you can't know for sure in which cases each of the icons should be used.

for example, there is an icon for selectin all items, but is there also one for de-selecting all items?

### my question

is there a website showing a list of all action bar items and their meanings?

in other words , are there any **guidelines as to when & where to use each icon** ?

is there maybe a website that contains more free-to-use icons for the action bar, that users can understand easily?

Comment: did you looked into res folders given into sdk?

Comment: i know there are files there, but files names don't always say where and when they are used and what they mean. even the files on the website i've written have names...

Answer (score 1):

Here is Link for Android Action Bar [Icon PAck](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html)

you can download a Zip file with all density based android Icons.

Comment: you don't get it. i know about the files and i know i can read their names, but i want to know if there is a way to find their meanings and when/where they are used. i've also wrote an example: there is an icon for selecting all items, but is there an icon for deselecting all items (or should i use the same one) ?  i can't find guidelines about where&when to use which icons.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Developer Tools by Eclipse , follow my lead:
`File > New > Other > Android Icon Set` ...

Comment: that's a cool feature, but it's still not an answer to my question. i've asked if there is a list with meanings for the icons, and not just the icons. if there are any guidelines as to when&where to use each icon. :(

Comment: But for your example about Selecting and Deselecting and ... , I personally always make differences by using negative colors such as black and white.